# How to use clipboard.js to copy <xmp> tag content and change button text from 'COPY' to 'COPIED' for a second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy-paste, clipboard.js

First it doesn't copy text from tags other than `<textarea>` or `<input>` tags. I want to use `<xmp>` tag because I need it to share code samples or demos.

Second how can we change the text of the button from "COPY" to "Copied!" just for one second, after one second it should revert back.

```
<xmp id="cpyhtml" class="lang-html prettyprint linenums:0 vj-codebox" style="background: #1B2B34;">
    <!--   any code here  -->
    <div class='slider-nav'>
      <div class='white'>any code here</div>
      <div class='black'></div>
      <div class='black'></div>
      <div class='black'></div>
      <div class='black'></div>
      <div class='black'></div>
      <div class='black'></div>
      <div class='black'></div>
      <div class='black'></div>
    </div>
</xmp>
<button class="cpybtn" data-clipboard-action="cut" data-clipboard-target="#bar">COPY</button>
```

I have tried using the above code with the following script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     new Clipboard('.cpybtn');
</script>
```

Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g8f3yy57/2/ for your convenience. Thank you.

Comment: You have two separate questions here: 1) allow `<xmp/>` 2) changing button text. Think you'd do better to ask for help individually so you get focussed answers.

Comment: Did you got any solution here ? I'm having the same challenge and unable to copy code from xmp. I can only make the whole xmp is selectable but user has to manually type command+c or Ctrl+C for copy.